# proving that $\lim \frac{x^2 - 1}{x - 1} =2$ as $x \rightarrow 1.$ by definition

Tags: limits

proving that $\lim \frac{x^2 - 1}{x - 1} =2$ as $x \rightarrow 1.$ by limit definition.

**My answer:** take $\delta \leq \epsilon$, am I correct?

Comment: Okay, go ahead.

Comment: Yes, choosing $\delta$ as such will work.

Comment: Where did $\epsilon$ come from and what will you do with $\delta$?  What will you do after you take the $\delta$?

Comment: I know every step I just wanted to be sure that my delta is correct ..... thank you @fleablood

Comment: Well, as $\frac {x^2 -1}{x-1} = x+1$ for all $x \ne 1$ and $|(x +1) - 2| < \epsilon \iff |x - 1| < \epsilon$ that would imply .you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I correct?

Your idea is correct however you'll have to **write much more**.

You first have to **repeat** the definition used by you:

> The definition of a $\lim\limits_{x \to a}$ ... is:
>
> For every value $\epsilon > 0$ there is a value $\delta > 0$ that ...

Otherwise the other people will ask you:

> What is $\delta$ and what is $\epsilon$?

At least one user already did this in the comment.

Then you claim that any $\delta \leq \epsilon$ satisfies this condition so for every $\epsilon$ such a $\delta$ exists.

You also have to **prove this**.

Otherwise I will claim that there is some value $x \in [0.6,1.4]$ which satisfies $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=100000$. If you don't prove your claim I won't prove mine either.

If my claim was right this would mean that the value $\delta = 0.5$ would not fulfill the condition for $\epsilon = 1$ so your claim that any $\delta\leq\epsilon$ fulfils the conditions would be wrong.